# Removing the non-base64 code from the FileReader without hard coding?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    // Going backwards: from bytestream, to percent-encoding, to original string.
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
```

I tried using atob, then I tried using the above. It's a pem file, doing:

```
openssl x509 -in valid.pem -text -noout
```

and it gives valid output.

The text content looks like: `data:application/x-x509-ca-cert;base64,QpDQXdHVVhWbFltVmp...` instead of this: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...` and it cannot be converted from base64.

I kept getting:

String contains an invalid character. The "data:application/x-x509-ca-cert;base64," part, is there a way to remove it from the reader.result?

```
const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (e) => {
    reader.result
    ...
}
```

I am guessing every pem file starts with "data:application/x-x509-ca-cert;base64,", but is there a way to remove it without hardcoding the string and removing that substring from the content?

I would like to avoid using:

```
replace('data:application/x-x509-ca-cert;base64,', '')
```

Comment: The base64 content starts after the comma in the text you show.  The rest is not valid base64.  Have you tried to decode just that part?

Comment: Actually, I had to change the question because I just realized it, I still thought that it would try to decode the string, but I guess base64 strings can't have commas and slashes.

Comment: "I would like to avoid using: <the most obvious and best-performing code possible>" :). Is there a reason to avoid that? I mean, you could gather the MIME types of the possible cert types and iterate over them, basically doing the same thing, but if it gets the job done...